# Create and a animation snake in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am having a project creating a snake game on WindowForm in C#. I have already created a snake, but using only rectangle. This snake is so ugly. Now I want to change this snake to animation snake with a list of image.
Please help me, I have only more 5 days for deadline
This is the code to create:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SnakeGame
{
  public class Snake
  {
    private Rectangle[] snakeRec;
    private SolidBrush brush;
    private int x, y, width, height;

    public Rectangle[] SnakeRec {
        get { return snakeRec; }
    }

    public Snake() {
        snakeRec = new Rectangle[3];
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

        x = 40;
        y = 10;
        width = 10;
        height = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < snakeRec.Length; i++) {
            snakeRec[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            x -= 10;
        }
    }

    public void drawSnake(Graphics paper) {
        foreach (Rectangle rec in snakeRec) {
            paper.FillRectangle(brush, rec);
        }
    }

    public void drawSnake() {
        for (int i = snakeRec.Length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            snakeRec[i] = snakeRec[i - 1];
        }
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].Y += 10;
    }
    public void moveUp()
    {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].Y -= 10;
    }
    public void moveRight()
    {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].X += 10;
    }
    public void moveLeft()
    {
        drawSnake();
        snakeRec[0].X -= 10;
    }

    public void growSnake() {
        List<Rectangle> rec = snakeRec.ToList();
        rec.Add(new Rectangle(snakeRec[snakeRec.Length - 1].X,      snakeRec[snakeRec.Length - 1].Y, width, height));
        snakeRec = rec.ToArray();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Please show to me, how to share code

Comment: Well, copy your code and paste it into your question? Ideally, use the code formatting tools in the toolbar.

Comment: I tried but stackoverflow said, the format was not correct!!!! :<

Comment: post your code we will edit it.no worries